# Reflection in Windows Universal Apps

Tags: c#, reflection, win-universal-app

I need to use the **GetProperties** method so I can test whether any properties in a particular class has a specified custom attribute. However it doesn't appear as though Windows Universal Apps supports this:

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties()
```

Raises the error:

```
'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetProperties' and no extension method 'GetProperties' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What do I need to reference in order to make use of the full reflection library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have `using System;` in your class?

Comment: Yes. I have also tried adding a portable class library to my project to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your using statements:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

Then you can use `obj.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties()` method. This method returns all properties defined on the specified type, including inherited, non-public, instance, and static properties. Keep in mind that this behavior is slightly different than the behavior of `GetProperties()` which is to return only the public properties.

Comment: At first I couldn't get this working, but I then added 'using System.Reflection;' and all is well. Thank you sir.